# help me pick the correct mosfets for low voltage coreless dc motors

Tags: arduino, mosfet, dc-motor

I'm building a minidrone based on an eachine using the same components  as the original but instead controlling it with an arduino nano, a bluetooth module and a  6 axis gyroscope. I had available 2 l293d's to drive the motors but the motors barely lift the drone. I was told the problem was that l293d is terrible option for lower voltage applications and I need to use low level mosfets(low Vgs) instead(also drones don't need to reverse the voltage of the motors).I'm planning to replace the H bridges with Si2302ds mosfets and shottky diodes.

Here are the respective datasheets :

SI2302DS
https://www.vishay.com/docs/70628/70628.pdf

1N5819
https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds23001.pdf

and this is what I found about the motors :

1.Operating condition
Rated voltage   3.4V DC
Direction of rotation   CW and CCW
Operating voltage range DC2.0--4.5V DC
perating temperature range  -10-50°C
Motor position  all position

2.Mearsuring condition
Motor position  horizontal or vertical
Power supply    regulated DC power supply assuring unquestionable measuring
regulated DC power supply assuring unquestionable measuring 10-30°C  30-95%
If the judgment is questionable,Measurent is to be made based on JIS Standard Testing Condition(20+2°C,65+5% )
Direction of rotation   viewed from output shaft side

3.Electrical characteristics
Items   Specification   Standard value
No Load speed   67000rpm±15%    67000 rpm
No Load current 200mA max   180mA
Starting voltage    0.8V max    0.5V DC
Stall current   240mA±5%    240mA
Terminal resistance 0.9Ω ±5%    0.9Ω
Insulation resistance   10MΩ min    AT 250V DC between
motor terminal and case

I've been told that the stalling current given is wrong since a 0.9ohm motor resistance results in a 3.7 / 0.9 = ~4Amp stall current (not 240mA).

I will also power the drone with the same battery that the eachine uses:

Battery Power:3.7V 260MAH 45C

My main concern is if I'm choosing the right mosfet for this project. I'll appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

0.8V start voltage max. implies low duty cycle PWM for starting

0.5V  DC Stall current 240mA±5  means DCR=500mV/240mA= 2 Ω

You must regulate the PWM for a soft start current of 240mA.

The MOSFETs only need to be < 100 mΩ to add 5% loss compared with 2  Ω  in motor.

Comment: this is what I found Rds On - Drain-Source Resistance: 72 mOhms. I'm guessing that should do it ? should I consider any other feature? Thanks for your time.